# Saltstack Manage and Query a Tally/Threshold via events and salt-call?

Tags: python, salt-stack

I have over 100 web servers instances running a [php](/questions/tagged/php) application using [apc](/questions/tagged/apc) and we occasionally (order of once per week across the entire fleet) see a corruption to one of the caches which results in a distinctive error log message.

Once this occurs then the application is dead on that node any transactions routed to it will fail.

I've written a simple wrapper around `tail -F` which can spot the patter any time it appears in the log file and evaluate a shell command (using [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) `eval`) to react. I have this using the `salt-call` command from [salt-stack](/questions/tagged/salt-stack) to trigger processing a custom module which shuts down the [nginx](/questions/tagged/nginx) server, warms (refreshes) the cache, and, of course, restarts the web server.  (Actually I have two forms of this wrapper, `bash` and Python).

This is fine and the frequency of events is such that it's unlikely to be an issue.  However my boss is, quite reasonably, concerned about a common mode failure pattern ... that the regular expression might appear in too many of these logs at once and take town the entire site.

My first thought would be to wrap my `salt-call` in a [redis](/questions/tagged/redis) check (we already have a Redis infrastructure used for caching and certain other data structures).  That would be implemented as an integer, with an expiration.  The check would call INCR, check the result, and sleep if more than N returned (or if the Redis server were unreachable).  If the result were below the threshold then `salt-call` would be dispatched and a decrement would be called after the server is back up and running.  (Expiration of the Redis key would kill off any stale increments after perhaps a day or even a few hours ... our alerting system will already have notified us of down servers and our response time is more than adequate for such time frames).

However, I was reading about the Saltstack event handling features and wondering if it would be better to use that instead.  (Advantage, the nodes don't have `redis-cli` command tool nor the Python Redis libraries, but, obviously, `salt-call` is already there with its requisite support).  So using something in Salt would minimize the need to add additional packages and dependencies to these systems.  (Alternatively I could just write all the Redis handling as a separate PHP command line utility and just have my shell script call that).

Is there a HOWTO for writing simple Saltstack modules?  The docs seem to plunge deeply into reference details without any orientation.  Even some suggestions about which terms to search on would be helpful (because their use of terms like pillars, grains, minions, and so on seems somewhat opaque).

Comment: Do you have a central monitoring solution like nagios which has the built-in functionality to run arbitrary scripts with user-defined delays between each run?

Answer (score 0):

The main doc for writing a Salt module is here: http://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/modules/index.html

There are many modules shipped with Salt that might be helpful for inspiration. You can find them here: https://github.com/saltstack/salt/tree/develop/salt/modules

One thing to keep in mind is that the Salt Minion doesn't do anything unless you tell it to do something. So you could create a module that checks for the error pattern you mention, but you'd need to add it to the Salt Scheduler or cron to make sure it gets run frequently.

If you need more help you'll find helpful people on IRC in #salt on freenode.